# Reduced number of rows using MICE package for imputation

Tags: time-series, imputation, r-mice

I have a multivariate time series. I'm using MICE package to fill NAs. This is resulting in reduced number of rows which I cant afford because it's time series data.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the data here.

My question is, is there any way I can avoid this ? Is there an option I can specify so the rows are not deleted? Or is it altogether a bad idea to use MICE for time series data?

Comment: `mice` generally does not delete lines, can you give a reproducable example or explain which lines are deleted and why?

Comment: There was a problem in the code. It is solved now. Thank you